# How I can execute two commands from VS Code Terminal?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I have to execute following command from VS Code Terminal. I am running my application in windows 10 machine.

```
set DEBUG=app & node app.js
```

when I run the above command the terminal gives me following error message.

```
    At line:1 char:15
   + set DEBUG=app & node app.js
   +               ~
   The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for 
   future use; wrap an ampersand in double quotation marks
   ("&") to pass it as part of a string.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], 
      ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmpersandNotAllowed
```

However when I run the same command from command window separately it executes fine as expected.

Answer (score 16):

Replace `&` with `;` like this.

```
set DEBUG=app;node app.js
```

`VSCode` uses `Powershell` as its terminal, And In `Powershell` the command separator is `;` NOT `&`

[Checkout MSDN Blog here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattn/2012/04/28/powershell-command-separator-is-and-not/)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can create script in `package.json`:

```
scripts:{
    "start": "set DEBUG=app;node app.js"
}
```

and run with command:

```
yarn run start // or npm run start (if you use npm)
```

`set` just can use for window, my suggest is use [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env).